# How do you enable UITableViewCell reorder without removing control with "setEditing " method?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

When I use  `[tableview setEditing:YES animated:YES];` to enable UITableViewCell reorder, the remove control appears too. How can I prevent that ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Implement [`-tableView:editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView%3aeditingStyleForRowAtIndexPath%3a) in the table view delegate and `return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone`.

Answer (score 0):

Add this method to youc code:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: this disables reordering too